# Structuring Categories in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello I looked at a few similar posts to what I am looking to do but none are the same to what I need to accomplish. I am trying to come up with my structure for categories using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to make categories for lets say...Clothing, Electronics, Furniture, Tools......and so on.

I am looking at a 3 field table to start with a category table (category ID (PK), categoryname, parentID) which from what I am finding is a standard practice and can go several layers deep without having to restructure.

The problem lies where it is fine for lets say (electronics-cd players-cd changer), (electronics-lighting-studio lighting) or (clothing-womens-skirts), (clothing-womens-pants) perhaps one level deeper?

What do I do for brands? I was planning to have a brand table (brandID(PK),Brand)
then Category_Brand table  (categoryID, BrandID) to link brands to categories when I want to use a cascading dropdown list that populates from the database.

What do I do for deeper attributes where the rest of the attributes apply to the item itself, but are dependent on the category? color, pattern, material, size? which can apply to clothing, but not to electronics or tools, also Mens clothing has different sizing than womens clothing.
Or furniture where I want to store dresser dimensions and color, or beds where I want to store bed size (king, queen, twin) and to store the type (Spring, air, foam, water)

What i need is to connect the item specific attributes to each item based on which category the item belongs to. On another forum I was suggested to just add all the misc. attributes to the item table and leave the ones I don't use null. I know that doesn't make sense, it seems to me that there should be different sub-attribute tables with fields that are related to the categories that they represent. i am thinking that clothing size for example would have a lookup table where each size has a (sizeid) and a link table for a many to many type relationship to connect the size with the (itemid), although there would need to be a few different size tables  because men's sizes and women's sizes are different or put then all in one table with the (categoryid) as a sort of parent foreign key, and dimensions for another item like (length, width, height) would be stored into its own table along with the (itemid) as the foreign key?

Or is it a good idea to store the (sizeid) or (dimensionid) right into the item table?

This seemed to be simple to me when I started, but the more I look at it the more I am getting confused as to the correct way to structure this, I want it to work good for performance as this may become a high volume application. But doesn't everyone wish that?

Comment: Outcome I am looking for is that users will be entering items into their own lists using category selection then being able to select the item's direct attributes that correspond with the item's category. Also users will be able to search the database for items either using categories or item names or users, and see the results of the items with the category and attributes that are part of that item.

Answer (score 0):

try to understand normalization first. Here is a good [article](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) for you.

Comment: Yes I get normalization, I took a database design class last year to get a better understanding, but what I am stuck trying to figure out is, I know the secondary attributes are directly and only a part of each exact item from the item table where my users will be entering products. What I need to do is to know which types of sub-attributes apply to each product based on what category the item is placed in.

Comment: @JerrodSand, happy to hear that. What is the exactly output you want?